# After setting change_state in class_init function, nothing else works

Tags: c, linux, plugins, gstreamer

I followed the [gstreamer's tutorial on how to write plugins](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/index.html?gi-language=c), and my goal is to create a video sink. For now I will just post relevant code, but if needed, I can upload whole plugin code somewhere. It will be an opensource anyway.

The class structure looks like this:

```
struct _GstIviOpenglSinkClass
{
  GstVideoSinkClass base_iviopenglsink_class;
};
```

and my class_init() function looks like this:

```
static void
gst_iviopenglsink_class_init (GstIviOpenglSinkClass * klass)
{
  GObjectClass *gobject_class = G_OBJECT_CLASS (klass);
  GstElementClass *gstelement_class = GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (klass);
  GstBaseSinkClass *gstbasesink_class = GST_BASE_SINK_CLASS (klass);
  GstVideoSinkClass *gstvideosink_class = GST_VIDEO_SINK_CLASS (klass);

  GST_DEBUG ("START");

  gobject_class->set_property = gst_iviopenglsink_set_property;
  gobject_class->get_property = gst_iviopenglsink_get_property;
  gobject_class->finalize = gst_iviopenglsink_finalize;

  gst_element_class_add_pad_template (gstelement_class,
      gst_pad_template_new ("sink", GST_PAD_SINK, GST_PAD_ALWAYS,
          gst_caps_from_string (VIDEO_SINK_CAPS)));

  gst_element_class_set_static_metadata (gstelement_class,
      "desc", "Sink/Video",
      "desc",
      "me <me@com.com>");

  gstbasesink_class->get_caps = gst_iviopenglsink_get_caps;
  gstbasesink_class->set_caps = gst_iviopenglsink_set_caps;

  /* makes problems?!? */
  gstelement_class->change_state = gst_iviopenglsink_change_state;

  gstvideosink_class->show_frame = gst_iviopenglsink_show_frame;

  GST_DEBUG ("END");
}
```

If I leave the class_init function like this, then the callbacks set_caps, get_caps, and show_frame, are not working (not being called at all). If I outcomment the assignment of the change_state, then these 3 callbacks are being called.

Am I doing something wrong in the class_init function, or is the problem lieing somewhere else? What can I do to debug this?

Comment: Well if you can pinpoint it to the `change_state` function your implementation is probably incomplete. Perhaps you want to call the base class's function do to the essentials and do your own things on top if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410388/after-setting-change-state-in-class-init-function-nothing-else-works#comment108637697_61410388) was correct - the problem is indeed in the function dealing with change_state. I took a look into [the source code for waylandsink](https://github.com/ford-prefect/gst-plugins-bad/blob/master/ext/wayland/gstwaylandsink.c) and found this weird line:

```
ret = GST_ELEMENT_CLASS (parent_class)->change_state (element, transition);
```

I have no idea what that line is doing, but apparently it is needed. And it is nowhere explained neither in the tutorial for plugins, nor in the page describing GstElementClass.

If someone can explain why is that needed, I would really appreciate it :)